# MMV mass file rename

Tags: rename, mmv

I'm having trouble figuring an mmv pattern. I have a bunch of video files with this pattern:

```
my.program.name.season.NN.episode.NN.-.title.avi
```

and I need to move them to:

```
my.program.name.sNNeNN.title.avi
```

I can't seem to get the right pattern...

Comment: Doesn't `mmv 'my.program.name.season.*.episode.*.-.*.avi' 'my.program.name.s#1e#2.#3.avi'` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR

```bsh
rename -n 's/^((\w+\.+){3})(.).*\.(.*)\.(.).*\.(.*)\.\-(\..*)$/$1$3$4$5$6$7/' *
```

- `\w+` matches one or more word characters, i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` [1]
- `\.+` matches one or more dot(`.`) character [2]

  **Note** that `\.` matches the `.` character. We need to use `\.` to represent `.` as `.` has special meaning in regex. The `\` is known as the escape code, which restore the original literal meaning of the following character.
- `(\w+\.+){3}` matches maximum 3 times of any accuracies of above [1],[2] group of characters starting from beginning(`^` matches the beginning of names) of the files name.
  This will match or return `my.program.name.`

  **Note** that extra parentheses around the regex is used for grouping of matching. Grouping match starts with `(` and ends with `)` and used to provide the so called *back-references*. A back-reference contains the matched sub-string stored in special variables *$1*, *$2*,*…*, *$9*, where $1 contains the substring matched the first pair of parentheses, and so on.
- `.` The metacharacter dot (.) matches any single character. For example `...` matches any 3 characters. so with this `(.)` we are matching the first character of `season` which it is `s`.
- `.*\.` matches everything after a single char in above until first `.` if seen. As you can see we didn't capture it as group of matches because we want to remove that from our name, where this matches `eason.`.
- `(.*)` matches everything after above match. This matches `NN`. Parentheses used here because we want to keep that in file name.
- `\.` matches a single dot after above match. A `.` after first `NN`.
- `(.)` again with this one we are matching the first single character after above match. this will return only `e`.
- `.*\.` will match everything after above match until first `.`. Will match `pisode.`.
- `(.*)` matches anything after last matched dot from above match. This will match second `NN`.
- `\.\-` matches a dot`.` followed by a dash`-`. Will match or return `.-`
- And finally `(\..*)$` matches a single dot`.` and everything after that which ends to end of the file name. `$` matches the end of the file name or input string.

Note: remove `-n` option to perform actual renaming.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this with perl's `rename` :

```
rename -n 's/
            (.*?s)eason\.(\d{2})\.episode\.(\d{2})\.-\.(.*\.avi)
            /$1$2e$3.$4/x
' my.program.name*
```

Once you are satisfied that this does what you want, remove the `-n` to actually perform the renaming.

Comment: @Jocala: The `-n` option inhibits the actual renaming operation, it just displays what files would be changed, and what they would be changed to. When run without an option `rename` does its work silently; supply a `-v` option for verbose mode, i.e., the same output in the terminal as with the `-n` option, but the files do actually get renamed.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it pure BASH:

```
netikras@netikras-netbook /tmp $ ls -l /tmp/*.*season.*episode.*avi
-rw-r--r-- 1 netikras netikras 0 Grd 16 10:29 /tmp/my.program.name.season.05.episode.07.-.title.avi
-rw-r--r-- 1 netikras netikras 0 Grd 16 10:29 /tmp/my.program.name.season.05.episode.32.-.title.avi
-rw-r--r-- 1 netikras netikras 0 Grd 16 10:29 /tmp/my.program.name.season.05.episode.35.-.title.avi
-rw-r--r-- 1 netikras netikras 0 Grd 16 10:29 /tmp/my.program.name.season.NN.episode.NN.-.title.avi

netikras@netikras-netbook /tmp $ for i in *.*season.*episode.*avi; do nn="${i/season./s}"; nn=${nn/.episode./e}; nn=${nn/.-./.}  ; echo "moving: $i ----> $nn"; mv $i $nn; done
moving: my.program.name.season.05.episode.07.-.title.avi ----> my.program.name.s05e07.title.avi
moving: my.program.name.season.05.episode.32.-.title.avi ----> my.program.name.s05e32.title.avi
moving: my.program.name.season.05.episode.35.-.title.avi ----> my.program.name.s05e35.title.avi
moving: my.program.name.season.NN.episode.NN.-.title.avi ----> my.program.name.sNNeNN.title.avi
```

This way you do not have to call any external applications, i.e sed/awk, to do the job. BASH can easily modify strings with built-in tools. You just replace 3 parts of your filename and create a new one. Then all what's left is to assign the new name to the file. No need to learn any of those spooky looking regexes to do simple job.